# AS3: Running over blocks in the game

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, block

I'm making a game in flash actionscript 3, it is almost done, but I have some problems.

Consider that in this game you are a character (for the moment a black square) and you have to get as high as possible by jumping on blocks that are falling. What I can do at the moment is jump and have a collision with the blocks (left - right) and jump onto the blocks.

When 2 blocks fall exactly next to each other (Block A falls next to Block B) Then I jump on Block A and I want to Run to Block B (just run without jumping) I get something very weird, I can't walk on blocks.

Here is the code where the problem should be:

```
package Classes
```

{
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import flash.ui.Keyboard;
    import Classes.KeyObject;

```
public class Player extends MovieClip
{
    var isJumping:Boolean = false;
    var jumpPower:int = 0;
    var ground:int;
    var stageRef:Stage;
    var key:KeyObject;
    var isDead:Boolean = false;
    var allBlocks:Array;
    var blockX:int;
    var blockY:int;
    var blockWidth:int;
    var blockHeight:int;
    var steps:int = 10;
    var upPressed:Boolean = false;
    public function Player(stageReff:Stage,allBlocks:Array)
    {

        stageRef = stageReff;
        key = new KeyObject(stageRef);
        this.allBlocks = allBlocks;
        ground = stageRef.stageHeight;
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,update);
        //addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyReleased);
    }

    function isHit()
    {
        for (var j = 0; j < allBlocks.length; j++)
        {
            if (this.hitTestObject(allBlocks[j]) && allBlocks[j] != isOnTopOf())
            {
                blockX = allBlocks[j].x;
                blockY = allBlocks[j].y;
                blockWidth = allBlocks[j].width;
                blockHeight = allBlocks[j].height;
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    function isHitTop()
    {
        for (var j = 0; j < allBlocks.length; j++)
        {
            if (this.PlayerBottom.hitTestObject(allBlocks[j].hitBoxTop))
            {
                jumpPower = 0;
                isJumping = false;
                this.y = allBlocks[j].y - allBlocks[j].height;
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    function isHitBottom()
    {
        for (var j = 0; j<allBlocks.length; j++)
        {
            if (this.hitTestObject(allBlocks[j].hitBoxBottom))
            {
                if (isJumping)
                {
                    this.y = allBlocks[j].y + this.height;
                    jumpPower=0;
                    isJumping = false;
                    isDead = false;
                    trace(isDead);
                }


                else
                {

                    isDead = true;
                    trace(isDead);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    function isOnTopOf()
    {
        for (var j = 0; j < allBlocks.length; j++)
        {
            if (this.PlayerBottom.hitTestObject(allBlocks[j].hitBoxTop))
            {
                trace("is WEL onTopOf");
                return allBlocks[j];
            }
        }
        trace("is NIET onTopOf");
        return null;
    }


    function update(evt:Event):void
    {
        if (!isDead)
        {
            isHitTop();
            isHitBottom();
            if (key.isDown(Keyboard.UP))
            {
                //Voorkomen dat hij 2x springt
                if (! isJumping)
                {
                    jumpPower = 12;
                    isJumping = true;
                }
            }

            if (key.isDown(Keyboard.LEFT))
            {
                if (this.x > stageRef.stageWidth - stageRef.stageWidth)
                {
                    this.x -=  steps;
                    if (isHit() == true)
                    {
                        this.x = blockX + blockWidth + 1;
                        //trace("is gehit maar staat er niet op");
                    }

                }
            }
            else if (key.isDown(Keyboard.RIGHT))
            {
                if (this.x < stageRef.stageWidth - this.width)
                {
                    this.x +=  steps;
                    if (isHit() == true)
                    {
                        this.x = blockX - this.width - 1;
                        this.y = blockY;
                    }
                }
            }


            if (isJumping)
            {
                this.y -=  jumpPower;
                jumpPower -=  2;
                isHitTop();
                isHitBottom();
            }


            if (! isJumping && ! isHitTop())
            {
                this.y +=  7;
            }


            if (this.y > ground)
            {
                this.y = ground;
                isJumping = false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,update);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
if (isHit() == true)
{
   this.x = blockX - this.width - 1;
   this.y = blockY;
}
```

You jump on block. Then you push a right arrow to go to the right (you will get to this line `else if (key.isDown(Keyboard.RIGHT))`). And in this code you check is there any collisions. Yes, they are, because you stay on the block. So your character gets this coordinates:

this.x = blockX - this.width - 1;
this.y = blockY;

But blockX, blockY and this.width are fixed. So your character is immobilized.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem. It was in the function `isHit()`. I have also added some new functionalities, like a menu, a score and a twitter feed.